# How do I control the serialization of properties in C# SOAP Proxy (xsd.exe)

Tags: c#, soap, xsd, xml-serialization

I'm consuming a SOAP web service in a C# application (.NET Framework 4.8) that uses a proxy generated via xsd.exe from the service's XSD.

In the XSD there is a field that expects a monetary amount, that is defined as follows:

```
<xs:simpleType name="HHAmountType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:pattern value="(\+|\-)?\d{1,7}\.\d\d"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And the service throws an exception back if I provide a value such as "0".  From looking at that XML Schema, it looks like it would expect that to be "0.00", and that matches some other documentation that describes the field.  What I can't work out is what to do to the generated class to allow me to output that number with 2 decimal places consistently.  The class has provided a property that is a decimal, that I'm setting to a value (in this case it's 0), and at the moment there are no additional attributes added to it.

```
/// <remarks/>
public decimal Amount {
    get {
        return this.amountField;
    }
    set {
        this.amountField = value;
    }
}
```

Can anyone steer me in the direction of any attributes etc. that would allow me to do this, or will I need to change this to a string property and handle that formatting myself or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
      private decimal _amountField { get; set; }
        public string Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return this._amountField.ToString("D2");
            }
            set
            {
                this._amountField = decimal.Parse(value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was going to be my last resort, as I mentioned in the question. Kind of hoping I can do something that won't get wiped out if the XSD is ever updated and the tool re-run etc.

Comment: Marked as answer, as I was unable to find anything else that would achieve the result without things like custom XML Serializers or SOAP interceptors etc.